# In CSS (w/o a @media query), how to apply/remove spacing when the component is a certain width

Tags: css, layout, flexbox, css-grid, spacing

I'm trying to figure out the following layout using only CSS and no @media query. Say I have the following starting point for HTML:

```html
<div class="layout">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

The `.layout` contains a block-level `.content` element which has 100% width but a max-width of `X`. (e.g., `X = 400px`.) As `.layout` widens, and right *after* the max-width of `.content` is reached, I would want to suddenly apply inline (right/left) spacing of `S` (e.g., `S = 16px`.)

This would cause the width of `.content` to shrink back at first, but as `.layout` width continues to grow, `.content` would grow back to `X` at which point the inline (right/left) spacing would continue to grow, keeping `.content` centered.

```
   400px              401px                 432px                   434px

+----------+    +---------------+    +-----------------+    +-------------------+
|.layout   |    |               |    |                 |    |                   |
|          |    |               |    |                 |    |                   |
|          |    |               |    |                 |    |                   |
|          |    |               |    |                 |    |                   |
+----------+    |   +-------+   |    |   +---------+   |    |    +---------+    |
|.content--|    |   |-------|   |    |   |---------|   |    |    |---------|    |
|----------|    |   |-------|   |    |   |---------|   |    |    |---------|    |
|----------|    | 1 |-------| 1 |    | 1 |---------| 1 |    | 1  |---------|  1 |
|--400px---| => | 6 |-369px-| 6 | => | 6 |--400px--| 6 | => | 7  |--400px--|  7 |
|----------|    | p |-------| p |    | p |---------| p |    | p  |---------|  p |
|----------|    | x |-------| x |    | x |---------| x |    | x  |---------|  x |
|----------|    |   |-------|   |    |   |---------|   |    |    |---------|    |
+----------+    |   +-------+   |    |   +---------+   |    |    +---------+    |
|          |    |               |    |                 |    |                   |
|          |    |               |    |                 |    |                   |
|          |    |               |    |                 |    |                   |
|          |    |               |    |                 |    |                   |
+----------+    +---------------+    +-----------------+    +-------------------+
```

I've been trying various configurations with `display:flex` and `display:grid` but can't get it to work. Here's the base I was starting from, but it does not have the spacing applied:

```css
/* "Inactive ingredients" would not be present in the actual implementation. */

.layout {
  /* Inactive ingredients: */
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 200px;
}

.content {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
  /* Inactive ingredients: */
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: P.S. I'm open to modifying the HTML, and I don't necessarily need the spacing to be applied via margins or padding. Just looking for the intended visual effect.

Comment: Why the media query restriction?

Comment: No media query because this layout may be nested inside other layouts which are not the full viewport width, and I would still need the same behavior.